# Excel: Multiple calculations on data in pivot-table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that gets populated with sales data from a database. From this i get a column with volume sold per day and sum it as a running total.

My problem is that I want to calculate the rate of change of the sales over time. Is there a way to add a calculated field that bases it's calculations on the running total?

Comment: So you do not have access to the source data, is that correct? You need to do work within the confines of a pivot table that is updated by linked data that you cannot alter?

Comment: @Raystafarian I do have access to the source data. But the aim is to make the data very user friendly for my colleges, some of which are bordering computer illiterate. But you have a good point. If I can do the running total in SQL instead, the problem should be solved.

Comment: Any updates for us?

Comment: Yes, I have added an answer to my question. But finally I decided to ditch excel all together. Mainly because excel has a tendency to crash when working with charts. So now I'm exploring RapidMiner to see if that works better for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this that I could figure out was to have the data fetched to an empty sheet as a normal table, instead of directly into a pivot table. I can then do more calculations on the data before turning it into a pivot table.